# How do I initiate multiple Futures at the same time to populate a single FutureBuilder ListView?

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart

So far what I have working is calling each future one after the other. All of which adds to the list.
However, sometimes one of the APIs may not work and therefore the rest that have not been loaded are bottlenecked. I'd like to start all the futures at the same time and have them all run in parallel to populate the list as results come on from any of them. How can I achieve this?

TLDR: Multi threading in dart/flutter?

Answer (score 2):

If you have 3 futures to execute in parallel:

```
Future<int> async1() async {
    await Future<String>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    return 10;
}

Future<int> async2() async {
    await Future<String>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    return 20;
}

Future<int> async3() async {
    await Future<String>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    return 30;
}
```

You can execute them in parallel and wait for all of them to finish by doing this:

```
Future.wait([async1(), async2(), async3()]).then((List<int> nums) {
     // This code executes in 3 seconds (3 endpoints in parallel)
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Will the code inside then() { } be executed each time one of the futures is finished or will it only be executed once after ALL of the futures are finished? Because I'd like the futures to populate the list as soon as they finish without waiting for the other futures.

Comment: No, it will execute only once all of the tasks are completed.